# Can you upgrade your Android Studio Preview to Android Studio beta (0.8.x)

Tags: android-studio

Has anyone been able to upgrade from within the Android Studio Preview (canary channel) to Android Studio beta or do you have to start with a fresh beta install?

Comment: I would recommend not, check out the mailing list. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/2g7s42cp39c. I'm getting this problem after upgrading, had to downgrade. The only way is to go to developer.android.com and download it manually as far as I can tell. The auto updater seems to not upgrade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot upgrade Android Studio Preview to Beta. These are two different products. You have to uninstall the preview and install the beta. It was straitforward for me. Beta setup can even import Preview settings. I just had to update my build.gradle file (on a small project) since I also downloaded API 20. It was not more painfull than an ordinary canary update of Android Studio Preview after all ;)

This page may be usefull for a step by step Android Studio Beta installation guide: http://bugapart.blogspot.fr/2014/06/install-android-studio-beta-for-dummies.html

Comment: I'm just curious why Android Studio still in beta version?

Answer (score 1):

As Dazzibao said, you cannot. However I would like to point out that I can't seem to find the Preview version being advertized for download anywhere on Google's site anymore. It would seem to me then **that it IS recommended to upgrade to Beta** as soon as possible if you're already on the Preview build. I would have posted a comment to reply directly to amchang87's comment on going against recommending it, but I simply don't have the rep yet.

I'm swapping mine out as I type this.